# How to access the Buttons that are child inside NavigationView

Tags: java, android, xml

How can I access the buttons that are child of RelativeLayout view inside NavigationView? However i am able to access the TextViews inside Header View using:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View header=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView tvUserName = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.drawer_user_name);
```

Is there any same way to access the buttons also?
here is my layout ->[Image of the layout from which i want to access buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmHVe.png)

and here is xml of the layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            android:id="@+id/header"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_below="@id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button3"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button4"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Button5"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you can just call

```
Button btn1 = (Button)navigationView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
```

or simply

```
Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
```

Comment: Sorry this error was from  NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View header=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView tvUserName = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.drawer_user_name); and i am still getting it: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.mbedded.mynav/in.mbedded.mynav.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that comment, sorry!

You don't have to have the direct parent of the view to find the view.

To get the user name textview you can simply call

TextView tvUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_user_name);

Comment: Thanks it worked without referring the immediate parent as you told.